# can't locate software after installing

Tags: software-installation

I installed gnome-mplayer using synaptic but now I can't find it to run it. Going to
Menu and searching just lists rythmbox. Ubuntu software wouldn't let me install mplayer
which is why I needed to install synaptic first.
Any suggestions,
Thanks,Bob

Comment: First, do this command in a terminal : `dpkg -l | grep mplayer` to see if it's really installed please. If you see "ii gnome-mplayer somethingsomething", then it really is on your system.

Answer (score -1):

Write in a terminal `gnome-mplayer` to launch it, if it is correctly installed.